# Evolution can't connect to google contacts

Tags: evolution

Hy guys,

if I want to view my gmail contacts in evolution, I get this: 
"requested ressource was not found" and then a link which leads me to the google developers, as if I was a developer.

Email works without any problems. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Cristian

Answer (score 1):

From google (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps)

Important: ClientLogin has been officially deprecated since April 20, 2012 and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail with a HTTP 404 response. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.

A solution is to install gnome-online-accounts, then enter your google account information in it.  It will take care of the authorization and let evolution talk to your google account.

Comment: installing that package, together with libgdata, seems to have removed the error message. However, none of my contacts are showing yet :( Tried to refresh, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [this](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=196881&p=1022208) link, Google uses `libgdata` which handles all the API/authentication stuffs. May be you can try to install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdata-common libgdata-dev libgdata19
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Ok, the direction is correct. The link you posted leads to the exact description of my problem. Unfurtunely the command you posted gives me: "package libgdata19 not found"

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? You can even try without libgdata19 and see if it is working.

Comment: 14.04 LTS and I tried it allready. Die not work. So I first exported goggle contacts as a .CVS for outlook and imported it in evolution. For the first it works... But thanks for your help!