# Evolution still can't connect to google contacts

Tags: evolution, contacts

Here 
[Evolution can't connect to google contacts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629754/evolution-cant-connect-to-google-contacts/631478#631478) 
I can read:

> A solution is to install gnome-online-accounts, then enter your google account information in it. It will take care of the authorization and let evolution talk to your google account.

I did enter my google account info in it, however, evolution hasn't started to talk to google account. Still get response: Source was not found: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps

Any other help?

Comment: Which version (Ubuntu)? It is working perfectly fine in 15.10